# How to programmatically get the network tags for a GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

If I create a new GKE cluster called `cluster-1`, the VMs in the cluster will all have an auto-generated network tag, e.g. `gke-cluster-1-d4732bcc-node`.

Is it possible, using `gcloud` CLI or something else, to programmatically retrieve this network tag using the cluster name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this by getting one of the auto-generated firewall rules for the GKE cluster and pulling out the target tag:

```
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster-name>
PROJECT_ID=<project-id>

NODE_NETWORK_TAG=$(gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project $PROJECT_ID --filter="name~gke-$CLUSTER_NAME-[0-9a-z]*-master" --format="value(targetTags[0])")

echo "$NODE_NETWORK_TAG"
```

Comment: Thanks ... this helped me solve one my issues

Comment: Hi @Andrew thanks. This helped me.
I'm using the beta-autopilot-private-cluster terraform module and while it does create egress firewall rules if you enable add_cluster_firewall_rules, it puts a tag with the cluster name on it rather than the instance tag that is applied to the ingress rules that are also created. Bit of a headache...

One thing re: the above snippet, perhaps PROJECT_ID would be better name for the var. I found I needed the PROJECT_ID rather than the name.

Comment: This assumes the tags were set as part of the cluster, but alas you can add/update tags with https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/autopilot-network-tags#network-tags-existing and the firewall rules are not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get a VM network tag with gcloud using the command

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE-NAME --project=PROJECT-ID --zone=INSTANCE-ZONE
```

The network tag information will be at the bottom and the output will be similar to:

```
tags:
  fingerprint: xxxx
  items:
  - tag1
  - tag2
  - tag3
```

All the VMs created by the cluster will have the same prefix.
gke-CLUSTER_NAME-NODE_POOL_NAME-RANDOM_STRING.

For example I created cluster “test-cluster” and I’m using only “default-pool”. One of my instances is [gke-test-cluster-default-pool-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx]

You can get all the instances names created by your clusters and put them in a variable similar to

```
name=`gcloud compute instances list --project=PROJECT-ID | grep gke | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Now you can use a FOR loop to run the command

```
for tags in $name; do gcloud compute instances describe $tags --project=PROJECT-ID --zone=ZONE; done
```

You can add a GREP at the end of the command just to fetch the network tag information , store the output in a file or parsed anyway you need it.